# Two way data binding not working on Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kendo-ui

I have a `kendo-dropdownlist` component that gets it's data from an API call. I had implemented this using the `kendo-datasource` component and everything worked fine. 
But I now have multiple `kendo-dropdownlist` components and instead of making an API call for every `kendo-dropdownlist` component, I am supposed to make only one API call and all the `kendo-dropdownlist` components should get it's data from the same JSON response. This `kendo-dropdownlist` is bound to a property called "currentData".

So what I am doing now is that I am declaring a `kendo-dropdownlist` component but not giving it any `data-source-ref`. Instead I am setting it's `data-source` attribute to a local data property called "source" which is an array of JSON.

Then in the `mount` life-cycle hook, I am making an API call and setting the response to the "source" data property. After this, the dropdown-items get populated in the `kendo-dropdownlist` but the "currentData" is not selected.

Component template:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
              v-model="currentData"
              :data-source="source.filter(s => s.type == 'something')"
              data-text-field="name"
              data-value-field="Id"
            ></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Component script:

```
export default {
  name: "SomeComponent",
  props: {
    prop1: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentData: this.prop1
      source: []
    };
  },
  mounted: async function() {
    await this.setDataSource();
  },
  methods: {        
    async setDataSource() {
      const formDTO = await SERVICE.getDataSource();
      this.source= formDTO.stakeholders;
    }
  }
};
```

I can confirm that one of the objects in the sources array has it's Id property equal to `this.prop1` .

Comment: Do you also confirm that `source` array contains elements of `type == something`?

Comment: @P3trur0 yes. I can confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

I can see in your `mounted` lifecycle hook, you have called `setDataSource` function. but you missed the reference to that function.

It should be called if you use

```
await this.setDataSource()
```

instead of

```
await setDataSource()
```

You can click on the any of the data and corresponding data is visible under `<p></p>` tag.

UPDATED StackBlitz Link:
Here is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sx2t3r-hmpquk?file=index.js)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is it, if it's referred correctly, it works fine. Just checked myself :)

Comment: my bad. My actual code contains `this` but I forgot to put it here while copying. But you example also doesn't solve the problem. Like I mentioned in the question, I am able to set the data-source, It is the binding that is not working

Comment: With the stackBlitz, you can also see that the data are populating from API.

Comment: Data are coming as per the selected data from Dropdownlist.